# access columns of row at index matlab

Tags: matlab, indexing

I have a text file A with N rows and 8 columns (example below):

```
1    2   0.02    0.28    0.009   0.04    0.03    0.16
2    4   0.04    0.21    0.4     0.04    0.03    0.13
```

if my variables x=2 and y=4 (I get during the program run -values change with every run.)
 I know the index of the row I need to get:

```
  rIndex = find((A{1}==x)&(A{2}==y));
```

here rindex = 2. 
I need to access row at rIndex and do operation with columns 3 to 8 in that row. i.e. i get values from another file based on x and y and divide those values by column values at rIndex row.

x_No = 5, y_No = 6;

```
B = horzcat((x_No-y_No)./A{3}(1),(x_No-y_No))./A{4}(1),(x_No-y_No)./A{5}(1),(x_No-y_No)./A{6}(1),(x_No-y_No)./A{7}(1),(x_No-y_No)./A{8}(1));
```

What B does right now is operates on all rows from A. I need only at particular rIndex.

Comment: I don't understand what you try to do. First you calculate `rIndex` but you don't even seem to use it. How is the computer supposed to know that you are only interested in changing the rows found in `rIndex`? Also, the unexplaned variables in hte last line don't make things any clearer.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin. I have edited my question considering unexplained variables. That is the question where can i use rIndex here? i dont know where to put it in the code. and matlab help on indeices didnt help.

Comment: @RobertP. This is Matlab. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its still not really clear what happens, but I think you can try something like this:

```
for r = 1:numel(rIndex)
    t=rIndex(r);
    result(r,:) = horzcat((x_No-y_No)./A{3}(t),(x_No-y_No))./A{4}(t),(x_No-y_No)./A{5}(t),(x_No-y_No)./A{6}(t),(x_No-y_No)./A{7}(t),(x_No-y_No)./A{8}(t));
end
```

I may be doing too much actually, but hopefully this helps.

Comment: this is very helpful thanks! if i use 'rIndex' instead of 't' that should work too right (without loop) because rIndex changes in the program run?